# using \dq in \subsections: has an extra }

Tags: macros, sectioning, sharelatex

I defined `\newcommand{\q}[1]{\dq#1\dq}` for the easier usage of the quotes.

Now I want to make subsections containing quotes...

```
\subsection{ \q{build} }
```

This line above causes an error for `l.42 ...4.2}"build"}{23}{subsection.6.4.2}`. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's the definition of `\dq`?

Comment: that's this quote: `"`

Comment: @rala: So what you're saying is you have `\newcommand{\dq}{"}` somewhere in your preamble? If so, I cannot replicate your problem.

Comment: no; I think its in the german babel package - this code works everywhere else, but not in subsections...

Comment: is there a way to check if all {} are correct set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\q}[1]{\dq#1\dq}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\q{build}}

\end{document}
```

The solution is simple: do

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\q}[1]{\dq#1\dq}
```

instead of `\newcommand`. However, the output is not really good, because the wrong opening quotes are used.

[image]